# how can I achieve the following table

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow

I want to create a table of the following form. Kindly help[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  What did you try so far and where exactly did you get stuck? For the column header "Evaluation criteria", you can use `\muticolumn`and for the entries in the first two columns, such as "CV", use `\multirow`(needs the `multirow` package).

Comment: Have a look at http://www.tablesgenerator.com/

Comment: Thank you. will have a look. I got stuck when multiple rows needs to be inserted in a single row. For example, Red, Green and Blue appears each time a new row starts.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `\multicolumn` and `\multirow`.
I left out the rightmost 6 columns because they are straightforward. And also the last 3 rows because they are similar to the 3 above. And I left out the boldface, just to make it simpler. If you add the other columns, change the `\cline`s to `\cline{...-10}`.

So here is my solution:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|p{2cm}|}{Evaluation criteria} & Multispectral Band & Proposed Method \\
  \hline
  \multirow{6}{*}{\(\chi^2\) test} & \multirow{3}{*}{CV} & Red & 2.18 \\
  \cline{3-4} 
  & & Green & 1.27 \\
  \cline{3-4} 
  & & Blue  & 0.44 \\
  \cline{2-4} 
  & \multirow{3}{*}{p-value} & Red  & 1.58e-33 \\
  \cline{3-4} 
  & & Green & 1.73e-40 \\
  \cline{3-4} 
  & & Blue & 2.39e-54 \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\multirow{3}{*}{R$^2$ test}} & Red & 0.90 \\
  \cline{3-4}
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & Green & 0.95 \\
  \cline{3-4}
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & Blue & 0.97 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]